# I can’t login to the server as the user I’ve created

Tags: server, public-key-encryption

I got “Permission denied (publickey)" using:

```
ssh $USERNAME@my-ip
```

Things I’ve done:

- Using Public/Private Key authentication, I can login to the server as root.
- I created a user in the sudo group
- I confirmed that my created user has sudo priveleges as I viewed auth.log successfully (`sudo cat /var/log/auth.log`)

I thought it was possibly because my server was unable to identify which key to use, as I have created multiple keys, so I specified which key to use:

```
ssh -i /path/to/key/id_rsa $USERNAME@my-ip
```

I got "Permission denied (publickey)" again.

Comment: Did you make sure to `chmod 700 ~user/.ssh` and `chmod 640 ~user/.ssh/authorized_keys`? Also check the ownership of these files.

Comment: Also, putting the user in a `sudo group` has nothing to do with log in errors.

Comment: I chmod accordingly (thank you @mdh.heydari).

I edited my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, uncommenting my `AuthorizedKeysFile    /etc/ssh/%u/authorized_keys`. I restarted ssh (`sudo service ssh restart`).

The permissions on my authorized_keys file is `-rw-r-----` - is this where the problem lies? (Still not working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Turns out I was missing an 's' in 'ssh' at the beginning of my authorized_keys file in my user. :) I also matched the permissions between the root and user authorized_keys files, though not sure if this helped truly.